# Is it possible to get siblings of parents?

Tags: jquery, dom, menu

I have the following menu structure:

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-item>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="">Item 1 <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item">Item 1.1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="">Item 3 <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="">Item 3.1 <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">Item 3.1.1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I have a bit of JS code that responds to clicks:

```
$( '.nav-menu' ).find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
    var _this = $( this );
    var _arrow = _this.children( '.dropdown-arrow' );

    // Get all '.dropdown-arrow' elements above this

    e.preventDefault();
} );
```

For example, if I click Item 3.1, I need to get its '.dropdown-arrow' span and those above it, this is, the one in Item 3.

Is this possible? If so, how?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not siblings of parents, they are children of parents. You need to use:

```
_this.closest('.menu_item').closest('.menu_item').find('.dropdown-arrow');
```

The above code will return the two.

Comment: Thanks! What if the menu structure is undefined levels deep? Can I use parents() instead of closest()?

Comment: @user1991185 You are absolutely right. You need to use the `parents()` here.